# Ceiling fan light glows with fan on and light OFF

Tags: lighting

I have a ceiling fan with a light.  I have a switch for the fan and a separate switch for the light.  When I have the fan on and the switch for the light off the light glows a little.  I checked the switches and fan/light wiring, everything looks correct.  What could be causing the light to glow?   Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Clarify if the switch for the light is a dimmer and also if the light installed in the fan is an LED type bulb.

Comment: Also, does the bulb glow if never turned on? Some bulbs do have a phosphorescent layer to smooth out any flickering, and that can glow for a surprisingly long time after light sources have been removed.

Comment: The switch is not a dimmer, the bulb is led.  If just the light is on and you turn it off it doesn't glow. If the light is off and you turn the fan on the light will glow.

Comment: Have you tried swapping in an incandescent bulb?

Comment: I've got the same problem with 3 of my 4 new fans. I've been informed by the distributor that it is probably an earth issue. I've not tested this hypothesis out yet. Did you resolve it in your case?

Comment: OK, in my case the electrician had left 1 of the 2 earth connections disconnected. This was the case on all 3 fans. Once these were plugged in correctly the glow went away. I didn't look closely, but I think that 1 earth connection went from the incoming conductor to the fan body. The second connection went from the fan body to the fan's electronics. i.e., for all intents and purposes it wasn't earthed.

Answer (score 3):

The dim light could be caused by the use of a two wire dimmer switch used in conjunction with an LED type bulb. Two wire dimmers require some small current flow to operate and that current will flow through the LED bulb. Many LED bulbs will be dimly lit by this small current. If an incandescant bulb was tried it would not be lit because the small amount of current required for the dimmer is not enough to heat the filament to glowing.

If this is indeed the cause for your issue you can try one of three things.

1. Replace the two wire dimmer and LED bulb with devices that are rated to operated correctly as a dimmer/LED combo.
2. Replace the two wire dimmer with one that has three wires (i.e. one that requires a Neutral connection). These need not pass current through the light in the OFF condition and instead use the hot and neutral connections to power the dimmer.
3. Even some dimmers that use a Neutral wire connection will still have some operational incompatibility with LED bulbs in low level settings. In these cases you may need to resort to a mechanical type switch or a smart switch that just has an On and Off function.